# Failed to check if file with German name is exist in the file system

Tags: java, perl, utf-8, local

**Background**:

I have 2 machines: one is running German windows 7 and my PC running English(with Hebrew locale) windows 7.
In my Perl code I'm trying to check if the file that I got from the German machine exists on my machine.
The file name is ßßßzllpoöäüljiznppü.txt

Why is it failed when I do the following code:

```
use Encode;
use Encode::locale;

sub UTF8ToLocale
{
  my $str = decode("utf8",$_[0]);
  return encode(locale, $str);
}

if(!-e UTF8ToLocale($read_file))
{
   print "failed to open the file";
}
else
{
   print $read_file;
}
```

Same thing goes also when I'm trying to open the file:

```
open (wtFile, ">", UTF8ToLocale($read_file));  
binmode wtFile;
shift @_;
print wtFile @_;
close wtFile;
```

The file name is converted from German to utf8 in my java application and this is passed to the perl script.
The perl script takes this file name and convert it from utf8 to the system locale, see UTF8ToLocale($read_file) function call, and I believe that is the problem.

**Questions:**
Can you please tell me what is the OS file system charset encoding?
When I create German file name in OS that the locale is Hebrew in which Charset is it saved?
How do I solve this problem?

**Update:**

Here is another code that I run with hard coded file name on my PC, the script file is utf8 encoded:

```
use Encode;
use Encode::locale;

my $string = encode("utf-16",decode("utf8","C:\\TestPerl\\ßßßzllpoöäüljiznppü.txt"));

if (-e $string)
{
  print "exists\r\n";
}
else
{
  print "not exists\r\n"
}
```

The output is "not exists".
I also tried different charsets: cp1252, cp850, utf-16le, nothing works.
If I'm changing the file name to English or Hebrew(my default locale) it works.
Any ideas?

Comment: the $LANG environment variable usually contains the console encoding

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 uses **UTF-16** internally [citation needed] (I don't remember the byte order). You don't need to convert *file names* because of that. However, if you transport the file via a FAT file system (eg an old USB stick) or other non Unicode aware file systems these benefits will get lost.

The *locale* setting you are talking about only affects the language of the user interface and the apparent folder names (`Programme (x86)` vs. `Program Files (x86)` with the latter being the real name in the file system).

The larger problem I can see is the internal encoding of the *file contents* that you want to transfer as some applications may default to different encodings depending on the locale. There is no solution to that except being explicit when the file is created. Sticking to UTF-8 is generally a good idea.

And why do you convert the file names with another tool? Any Unicode encoding should be sufficient for transfer.

---

Your script does not work because you reference an undefined global variable called `$read_file`. Assuming your second code  block is not enclosed in any scope, especially not in a `sub`, then the `@_` variable is *not* available. To get command line arguments you should consider using the `@ARGV` array. The logic ouf your script isn't clear anyway: You print error messages to STDOUT, not STDERR, you "decode" the file name and then print out the non-decoded string in your `else`-branch, you are paranoid about encodings (which is generally good) but you don't specify an encoding for your output stream etc.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but I'm still missing some pieces of information and I have taken what you said in to account. My issues are...

Comment: Sorry for the last comment it slipt away...  The thing is that even if I use the file name as is, with the utf8 encoding, its still doesn't work. I get the message: 'No such file or directory'. The main question is what happens when the operator -e is invoked on the file name? How does it search in the file system? Does it performing any convertion? What does it expect?

Comment: I believe it somthing to do with the system local, because if I'm changing the system local on my PC to German it works! but as long as my PC is on Hebrew local he will search for files that are encoded in Hebrew, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @shlomikl The `-e` operator tests if the given filename (relative or absolute path) exists. Doing no conversions at all is more likely to succeed than pulling some tricks. As I pointed out some directories have different names depending on the locale, but the file system encoding *never* changes.
Is the code you gave in your question complete? It cannot run in its current form.

Comment: The code is not complete but the rest is not relevant, just assume that the $read_file is valid defined variable and ignore the second part of of code: "open". Assume that The $read_file is the file name encoded in utf-8 and I would like to find out if it exists on my PC, that simple. I will post another code with hrad coded file name to demonstrate it's not working either.

Comment: @shlomikl It might be worth stripping that `encode` part. Once you `decode`d your string into a perl unicode string, the conversion to the locale encoding might happen automatic with the `-e` operator. In contrast, the `encode` function returns a byte string which interpreted as a normal string just messes things up.